# Is this a correct usage of triple integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The problem states:

> Find the volume of a region bounded by $x^2+y^2=4, \quad y=z, \quad
>  y+z=4 $

So the idea is to triple integrate over the given region. Since sketching stuff in 3D is rather difficult, I tried to avoid it doing this:

Since we're dealing with an intersection of a cylinder and two planes, and those to planes only deal with $y$ and $z$ coordinates, I've decided to disregard the x coordinate for a second and see what happens in the $Oyz$ plane. It would look something like this.

[image]

So, treating those two planes as lines and the cylinder simply as two lines with the equations $y=2$ and $y=-2$ I've managed to work out that the bounds for z are
$$-2 \leq z \leq 6$$
Now the next part is the one I'm not sure of how correct it is. It's pretty much Fubini's theorem, I'm just not sure how correct.

Since I have the bounds for $z$, now I need bounds for $x$ and $y$, which I've found by "looking from the top". Looking from the top we pretty much get a circle with radius 2, so I did a polar substitution $(x, y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ with $0 \leq r \leq 2, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

$$V(T) = \iiint_Tdxdydz = \int_{-2}^{6}dz\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{2}rdr
=\\ \    \frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{6}dz\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\cdot4 = 2\int_{-2}^{6}2\pi dz = 4\pi(6-(-2)) = 32 \pi$$

The thing I'm not sure of is whether I'm allowed to just "look from the top" as I said after finding the bounds for $z$ and treat everything from there as if it was in 2D.

Comment: The volume you computed is the volume of a cylinder with radius 2 and height 8. Instead your bounds of integration should not all be constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integral is not correct because the $z$ limits depend upon $r$ and $\theta$:

[image]

If you're clever, you'll see how the solid can be split in half horizontally and that the top half can be placed on the bottom half to make a cylinder, which has a trivial volume calculation.

If you insist on using a triple integral:

$$\int\limits_{r=0}^2 \int\limits_{\theta = 0}^{2 \pi} \int\limits_{z = 0}^{2 - r \cos (\theta)}\ r\ dr\ d \theta\ dz = 16 \pi.$$

Comment: And since I'm not clever, how would I find the bounds for the integrals?

Comment: Try to be clever (you'll become a better mathematician because of it):  Slice the figure horizontally along its mid-height plane.  Then take the bottom half and rotate it $180^\circ$ around the $x$ axis and stack in on top of the top half.  What figure results?  What is the formula for the volume of this figure?

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying. However, this problem is a part of the 'Triple integrals' chapter in my textbook so it would be better if I managed to solve it using triple integration instead of this method. There are many more similar problems and I doubt that every one of them will be solvable using these improvised and clever methods.

Comment: As far as I can see z can go below 0, so how come the lower bound is 0?

Comment: The best I've managed to work out is:
$\int_{-2}^{2}dx \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dy \int_{y}^{4-y}dz$
which, when switched to polar coordinates is similar to your thing but still not the same.

Comment: @Kay:  The reason the lower-limit on my $z$ range is $0$ is obvious once you look at the red plane of my figure (and notice a factor of $2$).